# Trouble binding custom object to custom user control

Tags: c#, xaml

I have created an object like this:

```
 public class Widget : INotifyPropertyChanged {
      int miValue;      

      public int Value {
           get => miValue;
           set {
                miValue = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value");
           }
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 }
```

Now, I have also created a user control that has a series of text boxes that bind to a property of the user control:

```
    public StatBlock ( ) {
        InitializeComponent( );
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public int Points {
        get => ( int )GetValue( PointsProperty );
        set => SetValue( PointsProperty, value );
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PointsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Points", typeof(int), typeof(StatBlock), new PropertyMetadata(0));

}
```

If I use this UserControl in a window, I can assign the `Points` property with a static value and everything works properly.  But if I bind to an object, then it doesn't work.  For testing, I have done the following:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <local:Widget x:Key="test" value="150"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource test}">
    <local:StatBlock Points="{Binding Value}" Width="65" Height="65"/>
    <TextBox Width="150" Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Value}"/>
</Grid>
```

This will only return a value of 0 in my user control, even though we can see that the value is 150.  In fact, the value in the standard `TextBox` is correct.  Did I miss something?  Thanks.

Comment: You are setting `DataContext` inside user control, so it can not inherit it from parent container while `TextBox` can. There should be binding errors in "Output" window.

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  I just set a name to the UserControl than changed the binding so that it had the ElementName in it.